# Bigquery - Sum current and previous row with condition

Tags: google-bigquery, sum, lag

I am new to SQL and I would like to do the following:

I have the following table: [image: table]

I have to build the "DateFinal" column with the following rules:

1. Everything must be grouped by the "Groupid" column
2. If Order = 1 then add "DateStart" + "Days"
3. If Order >1 then add the result of the previous row "DateFinal"(row 1) + "Days" (row2)

The result should be like this:
[image: table result]

How can I achieve this in bigquery?

Thanks a lot!

```sql
WITH Table0 AS 
(SELECT 
  Gruopid,
  DateStart,
  Orden,
  Days
FROM `project.test`
ORDER BY Gruopid,Orden),

Table1 AS
(SELECT
  *,
  CASE 
    WHEN Orden =1 THEN DATE_ADD(DateStart, INTERVAL Days DAY) 
    ELSE NULL END AS DateFinal
FROM Table0)


SELECT 
  *,
  CASE
  WHEN Orden> 1 THEN DATE_ADD(LAG(DateFinal) OVER (PARTITION BY Gruopid ORDER BY Orden),INTERVAL Days DAY)
  ELSE NULL END AS DateFinal
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select *, 
  datestart + sum(days) over(partition by groupid order by `order`) datefinal
from your_table
```

with output

[image]